# Correct design for Many-To-Many when by default everything mapped to everything

Tags: mysql, rdbms

So i usually goes with the Junction Table approach to implement M2M.

But I'am now facing the trouble of Mass mapping (eg: by default everything is mapped to evreything)

So M objects will be connected to N objects, and when a new M object is being created, a new N lines will be added to this table (and vice versa).

This scenario is the default behavior of my system, obviously any M can remove any mapping connection (and vice versa).

Should i stick the "traditional" junction table approach? or is there a better design pattern for this?

An example would be:
I have a file-system with a big amount of users and files.
All users can see all files **by default**, but an Adminstator can decide to remove view premission for certain users for certain files.
 

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a real example. This sounds very theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

An "all-to-all" relationsship is done by a `cross join`, you do not need a junction-table for that:

```
select * from M cross join N;
```

If you additionally want the ability to exclude specific combinations, you can add a "junction" table and check if the combination does NOT exist. There are several options to do so in your queries (`left join`, `not exists`, `not in`, ...):

```
create table M (id int);
create table N (id varchar(1));
create table MN_excluded (idM int, idN varchar(1));

insert into M (id) values (1), (2), (3);
insert into N (id) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C');
insert into MN_excluded (idM, idN) values (2,'A'), (3,'B');

select * from M 
cross join N
left join MN_excluded 
on MN_excluded.idM = M.id and MN_excluded.idN = N.id
where MN_excluded.idM is null;

select * from M 
cross join N
where not exists (
  select 1 from MN_excluded
  where MN_excluded.idM = M.id and MN_excluded.idN = N.id);
```

But be aware that (in case of your filesystem example) adding a new user would allow him full access to everything. So if you have a file `/etc/passwd` and defined restrictions for all 201 existing users except `root`, adding a new user would allow him access to it, unless you explicitly add a combinations to deny it. In most real world problems, this behaviour is not wanted.

A design that still "allows" combinations, but doesn't require you to add all `M * N` combinations, would be to use (access) groups. You could e.g. use the junction tables `M_group` and `N_group`, where you would add each entry for `M` and `N` once (with the same group `ALL`) to allow full access for everyone. Exception could be done by adding some files and users to the group `ADMIN`, and removing the group `ALL` for those files. If you make one of those relations (probably the "file" side) a 1:1 relation, you can then even use a simply `join` over all tables to get all allowed combinations; otherwise you would have to use `exists`, because users and files could belong to several groups, thus `join` could return some `(user, file)`-combinations more than once.

That was just to give you an idea to alternative designs. If you really just need an "all-to-all"-relation with some exceptions, `cross join` is the way to go.